# Exporting Data from a cube to Database using Turbo Integrator (ibm cognos TM1)

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I am using Turbo Integrator for the first time to export data from a tm1 cube to a database.
I know that for exporting data to a file we can use something like this :

```
ASCIIOUTPUT( zFile, 'Dim1','Dim2','Amount');
```

But I would love to know the syntax used to export it to a database ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which TM1 (IBM Planning Analytics) Version you are using. Maybe this info can help you. It's for version 2.0.x:

Open an ODBC-connection: `ODBCOpen(Source, ClientName, Password);`

Write your output as SQL: `ODBCOutput(Source, SQLQuery, [SQLQuery2, SQLQuery3, ...]);`

Close the ODBC-Connection: `ODBCOutput(Source, SQLQuery, [SQLQuery2, SQLQuery3, ...]);`

An other way is to do it by command. You could write an batch file an run it by a TI-process

```
ExecuteCommand(CommandLine, Wait);
```

You can find additional information on the IBM Webside:
[IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_prism_gs.2.0.0.doc/r_tm1_ref_tifun_odbcoutput.html)